# Access denied for user 'consult'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, html, css

I am using *bluehost* domain. I want to connect database but I don't know password. After the long war I found the username and localhost name. I am a beginner. Help me to find the phpmyadmin password.

This my php database conection code.This code is worked in localhost.

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'consult', '');
if (!$link) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
 // make foo the current db
  $db_selected = mysql_select_db('consultv_hrms', $link);
  if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: _"I m using bluehost domain."_ Why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the admin can reset database password. In this case you need to follow the instructions given by your hosting provider

1. Log into the cPanel
2. Click the MySQL Databases icon under the "Databases" category
3. Change the password

Refer [this](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2220) for detailed instructions